# Enter key to create new row and focus current input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table width="500" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>No.</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Phone</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" name="name_1" id="name_1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" name="age_1" id="age_1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="phone_1" class="inputs lst" id="phone_1" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    var i = $('table tr').length;

    $('.lst').on('keyup', function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13) {
            html = '<tr>';
            html += '<td>' + i + '</td>';
            html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs" name="name_' + i + '" id="name_' + i + '" /></td>';
            html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs" name="age_' + i + '" id="age_' + i + '" /></td>';
            html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs lst" name="phone_' + i + '" id="phone_' + i + '" /></td>';
            html += '</tr>';
            $('table').append(html);
            $(this).focus().select();
            i++;
        }
    });

    $('.inputs').keydown(function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13) {
            var index = $('.inputs').index(this) + 1;
            $('.inputs').eq(index).focus();
        }
    });
</script>
```

In this form initially focus on first text box ,then press **enter key** it automatically focus to nearby input fields at dead  end while we press **enter Key** then it create new row and focus to initial input field presented in newly created row 
after that while we press enter key it doesn't focus to near by text field please help to resolve this issue.
In first row it work correctly while we entering second row it not working
**please help**

Answer (score 2):

You need [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically generated elements like following.

```js
var i = $('table tr').length;

$(document).on('keyup', '.lst', function(e) {
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code == 13) {
    html = '<tr>';
    html += '<td>' + i + '</td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs" name="name_' + i + '" id="name_' + i + '" /></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs" name="age_' + i + '" id="age_' + i + '" /></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs lst" name="phone_' + i + '" id="phone_' + i + '" /></td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    $('table').append(html);
    $(this).focus().select();
    i++;
  }
});

$(document).on('keydown', '.inputs', function(e) {
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code == 13) {
    var index = $('.inputs').index(this) + 1;
    $('.inputs').eq(index).focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="500" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>No.</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Phone</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" name="name_1" id="name_1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" name="age_1" id="age_1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="phone_1" class="inputs lst" id="phone_1" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks it work, but select2 auto complete not working in dynamically added rows

Comment: Initialize `select2` for the new elements after new row is added to the body each time.  @HariKannan

Comment: sorry i am using bootstrap-select.min.js and bootstrap-select.min.css <br>
there is only a class="selectpicker" like this <select class="inputs form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true"> other no ititialization